# Nginx multiple root depending on user agent

Tags: php, nginx

I have two applications one for mobile devices  and other for other devices.

What I am trying to do is to show both application on the same domain instead of 2 different domain

I have google it but every one it showing url redirection.

Below is the code which, I have trying

```
server {
        listen 80;

        set $root /var/www/ng/webApplication;

        if ($http_user_agent ~* "android|blackberry|googlebot-mobile|iemobile|ipad|iphone|ipod|opera mobile|palmos|webos") {
            set $root /var/www/html/mobileApplication;
        }

        root $root;
}
```

**but nginx stop working if add this condition.**

**Edit**

**nginx -t** result

nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok

nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful

**Edit**
**access.log**

180.151.19.20 - - [02/Jul/2019:05:12:10 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 178 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:67.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/67.0"

also in browser it shows 404 Not Found

Comment: Whats `nginx -t` say when you make your edit? Are the paths correct, they differ slightly ng/html.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I have edit the question and added the result of nginx -t

Comment: Just in case this is a mistake, but your server block is missing a closing brace `}`

Comment: What do mean by Nginx stops working? Do you have access logs and error logs that demonstrate the problem you are seeing?

Comment: @steadweb I forgot to add in question but syntex is fine, I have checked nginx -t

Comment: @RichardSmith nginx stop working means it not redirecting anywhere in the browser, allow me some time to add server logs as well. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both applications can respond independently. You can try to use the reverse proxy option. [Here is an example](https://blog.dchidell.com/2017/06/16/nginx-reverse-proxy-based-on-user-agent/).

```
    proxy_pass http://localhost/webApplication;

    if ($http_user_agent ~* "android|blackberry|googlebot-mobile|iemobile|ipad|iphone|ipod|opera mobile|palmos|webos") {
        proxy_pass http://localhost/mobileApplication;
    }
```

Comment: we don't have a way to set root as I have asked in the question ?

Comment: I'm not sure if we can. Would need to dig a little deeper to see that. But, you can use the reverse proxy solution setting other URLs with the roots you want and pointing to them.